# Formatting piped text in zenity

Tags: formatting, zenity, mediainfo

I'm trying to show some mediainfo output in a Zenity dialog, using

```
mediainfo 00000.MTS | zenity --text-info
```

and [here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQfvm.png) there result. As the image shows, the text is badly formatted because of spaces, while it shows just right [in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsOLf.png).

Can I change this? 
Also, is it possible to format particular strings of text (e.g: the "General" and "Video" headers)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> the text is badly formatted because of spaces, while it shows just right in terminal.  Can I change this?

Yes, just change the font to one that is monospaced:

```
mediainfo 00000.MTS | zenity --text-info --font='DejaVu Sans Mono'
```

> is it possible to format particular strings of text

No, this is not possible with `--text-info`.

Comment: I wonder why this got downvoted. It looks to me as a good answer. +1

Comment: FYI, as of version **3.14.0** of **zenity**, the depicted `font` option does not appear to be available when using zenity's `--list` format...